# Не получается воспроизвести файл с локального ноителя с помощью Media Element .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

Сам Media Element работает без ошибок, видео ролик приведенный в обучалке воспроизводит. Но какие либо файлы отказывается воспроизводить.
Пробовал `<toolkit:MediaElement Source="embed://testvideo.mp4" ShouldShowPlaybackControls="True" />`
с добавлением файла в папку raw.
Также через `<toolkit:MediaElement Source="filesystem://.../>` С разных мест.